# Why can't I compare two Strings when using getters?

Tags: java, string, methods, compare

```
public class HighSchoolStudent {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private double gpa;

    public HighSchoolStudent(String firstname, String lastname, double gpa) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public double getGpa() {
        return gpa;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (lastname + ", " + firstname);
    }
}



import java.util.*;

public class StudentSearchSort {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      HighSchoolStudent Mike = new HighSchoolStudent("Michael", "Jackson", 3.5);
      HighSchoolStudent Roger = new HighSchoolStudent("Roger", "Federer", 3.9);
      HighSchoolStudent Serena = new HighSchoolStudent("Serena", "Williams", 3.7);
      HighSchoolStudent Kobe = new HighSchoolStudent("Kobe", "Bryant", 3.3);
      HighSchoolStudent Stephen = new HighSchoolStudent("Stephen", "Curry", 4.0);
      HighSchoolStudent Tiger = new HighSchoolStudent("Tiger", "Woods", 2.9);
      HighSchoolStudent Kanye = new HighSchoolStudent("Kanye", "West", 1.5);

      ArrayList<HighSchoolStudent> studentlist = new     ArrayList<HighSchoolStudent>();
  studentlist.add(Serena);
  studentlist.add(Tiger);
  studentlist.add(Mike);
  studentlist.add(Kanye);
  studentlist.add(Roger);
  studentlist.add(Stephen);
  studentlist.add(Kobe);

 // for (int i = 0; i < studentlist.size(); i++) {
 //    System.out.println(studentlist.get(i));  
 // }

//  System.out.println(highestGpa(studentlist));
  }

   public static String highestGpa(ArrayList<HighSchoolStudent> students) {
  HighSchoolStudent smartest = null;
  double highestgpa = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
     if (students.get(i).getGpa() > highestgpa) {
        smartest = students.get(i);
        highestgpa = students.get(i).getGpa();
     }   
  }
  return smartest.toString() + " GPA: " + smartest.getGpa();
  }

   public static void lastNameSort(ArrayList<HighSchoolStudent> students) {
  HighSchoolStudent[] sortedlist = new HighSchoolStudent[students.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
     for (int j = i; j < students.size(); j++) {
        int num = 10;
        if(num <= 0) {
           sortedlist[i] = students.get(i);
           sortedlist[i+1] = students.get(i+1);
        }else {
           sortedlist[i] = students.get(i+1);
           sortedlist[i+1] = students.get(i);
        }   
     }   
  }     
  }

 public static String lastNameSearch(ArrayList<HighSchoolStudent> students,     String lastname) {
  for(HighSchoolStudent student : students ) {
     if (lastname.equalsIgnoreCase(student.getLastName())) {
        HighSchoolStudent temp = students.get(i);
        return (i+1) + ": " + temp.toString();
     }
  }
  return null;
  }
  }
```

updated. this is everything i have. i dont know what to do anymore. and now im just typing random stuff so it will let me edit these changes in. i keep on getting compiling errors that say error: cant find symbol and an arrow points to the period before .getLastName() , i have no clue how to fix it

Comment: What symbol can't it find?

Comment: You should post the definitions for `HighSchoolStudent`, your expected output, and your actual output

Comment: it wont compile for me, i just want to know why

Comment: This code looks fine to me. Without the rest of the code, it's really hard to say why it won't compile. It could be that the project settings aren't configured correctly for your IDE, or you could've missed a file when downloading it or something. We at least need the compiler error you're getting

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 errors.

1. You made a typo. The parameter is named `students`, not `student`. You missed an 's'
2. `students` is an `ArrayList`, which doesn't have a `getLastName()` method. You need call `getLastName()` on a `HighSchoolStudent` object like so: `students.get(i).getLastName()`

This is what you have:

```
public static String lastNameSearch(ArrayList<HighSchoolStudent> students,     String lastname) {
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
    //  if (lastname.equalsIgnoreCase(student.getLastName())) {
            //                        ^ this is where your error is
            //                          you missed an 's'...
            // vvv replace above with this line vvv
        if (lastname.equalsIgnoreCase(students.get(i).getLastName())) {
            HighSchoolStudent temp = students.get(i);
            return (i+1) + ": " + temp.toString();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: i put the main method first, should i change the order?

Comment: Shouldn't matter in Java

Comment: @nick23 What IDE are you using?

Comment: i dont know what an IDE is. im using jgrasp.

Comment: @nick23 That's an IDE, which stands for Integrated Development Environment. It's basically a big editor that highlights the important parts of your source code, and eases development process in general. Try starting a new project in jGrasp with the 2 files I have up there

Comment: same thing happens for me

Comment: i had it like that before, and it still doesnt work, i was trying what other people were doing

Comment: @nick23 That's weird, 'cause when I copied the code you had up there before you gave up, I got the same error at the same spots you were getting them. There were only 2 so I fixed those, and it compiled and ran with the test cases uncommented. Try copying and pasting my code. You didn't have it exactly like this before. You had typos

Answer (score 0):

use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead

```
 if (lastname.equalsIgnoreCase(students.get(i).getLastName())) {
```

you are converting whole object to string instead of give full name.

```
String temp = students.get(i).getFirstName()+" " + students.get(i).getLastName();

 return (i + 1) + ": " + temp;
```

Comment: if (lastname.equalsgnoreCase(students.get(i).getLastName())) {                    this still doesnt work, it gives me a compiling error that points to the period before getLastName()

Comment: it is equalsIgnoreCase not equalIgnoreCase. yes try that.

Comment: i just double checked, that is what i typed

Comment: I dont understand I copy paste same code it doesnt give any error at all.

Comment: really? it wont compile for me

Answer (score -1):

```
public  static String lastNameSearch(List<HighSchoolStudent> `students`, String lastname) {
  for(HighSchoolStudent student:students) {
     if (lastname.equals(student.getLastName())) {
        HighSchoolStudent temp = student;
        return (i+1) + ": " + temp.toString();
     }
  }
  return null;
```

Comment: this doesnt work either, i get a compiling error that says it cannot find symbol

Comment: coppy  line no 59 in StudentSearchSort.java here

Comment: if (lastname.equals(student.getLastName())) {

Comment: it has a problem with any line where i use compareTo or equals because  i use .getLastName() and i dont know why